# DataView sort method - which sorting algorithm is used?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sorting

I am using VS2012, .NET Framework 4.5. I need to know which sorting algorithm is used
in DataView.Sort?

My code:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Word");

table.DefaultView.Sort = "Word";//after that row, DefaultDataView is sorted
```

So what sorting algorithm is used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sort method in DataView implements the **Quicksort algorithm**.  It chooses an arbitrary midpoint, places all the values lower than the midpoint's to the left and all the higher values to the right.  Then it applies itself recursively to the left and right sections.  Eventually it will recurse down to sections that cannot be divided into smaller sections (i.e., when a section consists of a single array member), at which point the sort has completed.  Using big-O notation, we can say that this algorithm executes in **O(n log n)** time, which is about as efficient as you can expect from a sorting algorithm.  As long as each iteration of the sort divides the set of indices into two equal parts, we are dealing with a **logarithm of base 2**
To prove all this you would have to instrument the System.Data code and check run-time performance with a testing tool.

**UPDATE:**

You could Take a look at [Reflector Utility](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and follow this post...Its all explained here [DataView Sort](http://geekswithblogs.net/chrisfalter/archive/2006/08/15/88057.aspx)

Comment: Appreciate your answer. How do you know that quicksort is used? I've tried .NET reflector, but couldn't find the point where sorting really takes place.